# Error message when installing bootstrap into Angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, visual-studio

I'm working in Visual Studio and trying to install bootstrap from the CLI embedded in VS.

```
 PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\helloWorld> npm install --save bootstrap
```

I get the following message which I assume is an error. I cannot find out what it means and am wondering how to move forward.

```
 hello-world@0.0.0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\helloWorld
 +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.0.1
 +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.0.1
 `-- bootstrap@3.3.7

  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
 fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
 {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
 npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || 
 >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
 npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || 
 >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors, else the install would not succeed. To fix the warnings from Codelyzer you can simple update the version from Codelyzer which supports Angular up to <6.0.0

Comment: OK. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

(1)You can check bootstrap is installed or not by checking whether there is entry in `package.json`. By providing path of `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.min.js` in angular-cli.json, one can easily use them.

(2)Moreover, when you install through `npm` a folder is created in node Modules.

Whenever, you install anything through `npm` there maybe some `warn` message but they dont have any effect and can not be conidered as 'errors'.